# Programmatically change field separator (FS) and recompute current record in gawk?

Tags: awk

I want to change the field separator (`FS`) only for a specific record, and I want the record (`$0`), fields (`$N`), and number of fields (`NF`) to be recomputed using the new field separator. But it doesn't seem to work.

**Example:** Here I have a single line which gets interpreted as three fields separated by whitespace. If I change the field separator to `n` and force the record to be reconstituted (`$1 = $1`), the record remains the same, as can be seen by printing `$1`:

```bash
$ echo 'one two three' | awk '1 {FS="n" ; OFS=":" ; $1 = $1 ; print $1}'
> one
```

But I would expect the output to be:

```bash
> o
```

The trick of forcing the record to be reconstituted by running `$1 = $1` is taken from the [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html). So I would expect it to work. I'm not sure what could be the problem:

> It is a common error to try to change the field separators in a record simply by setting `FS` and `OFS`, and then expecting a plain `print` or `print $0` to print the modified record.
>
> But this does not work, because nothing was done to change the record itself. Instead, you must force the record to be rebuilt, typically with a statement such as `$1 = $1` [...]

(I'm using GNU Awk 5.2.2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding

> I want to change the field separator (FS) only for a specific record

Your code might be clearer/simpler if you use `split()` for that record instead.

You're mixing up 2 concepts - rebuilding $0 and resplitting $0.

**Rebuilding $0:** When you modify or otherwise assign a value to a field, $0 is rebuilt from the fields replacing every FS with OFS, e.g.

```
$ echo 'one two three' |
    awk '{FS="n" ; OFS=":" ; $1 = $1 ; print; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i, $i}'
one:two:three
1:one
2:two
3:three
```

**Resplitting $0:** When you modify or otherwise assign a value to $0 (other than as a result of it being rebuilt due to changing a field), $0 is resplit into fields using the existing FS value, e.g.

```
$ echo 'one two three' |
    awk '{FS="n" ; OFS=":" ; $0 = $0 ; print; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i, $i}'
one two three
1:o
2:e two three
```

Now try to understand the following results to see if you understood the above statements:

Rebuilding then Resplitting:

```
$ echo 'one two three' |
    awk '{FS="n" ; OFS=":" ; $1 = $1 ; $0 = $0; print; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i, $i}'
one:two:three
1:o
2:e:two:three
```

Resplitting then Rebuilding:

```
$ echo 'one two three' |
    awk '{FS="n" ; OFS=":" ; $0 = $0; $1 = $1 ; print; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i, $i}'
o:e two three
1:o
2:e two three
```

Comment: Wow, our comments were deleted. Was it you or was it stack exchange?

Comment: It wasn't me...

Answer (score 7):

Looking around the quoted text, I see:

> Finally, there are times when it is convenient to force `awk` to rebuild the entire record, using the current values of the fields and `OFS`.

Followed a little later by:

> There is a flip side to the relationship between `$0` and the fields. Any assignment to `$0` causes the record to be reparsed into fields using the *current* value of `FS`.

From the lack of mention of `FS` in the former sentence and the emphasis on it in the second, I think the expected way is that only `$0 = $0` will cause the fields to be re-calculated; the others will only cause the record to change for *output* from whatever the values of the fields are without attempting to parse them:

```
% echo 'one two three' | awk '1 {FS="n" ; OFS=":" ; $0 = $0 ; print $1}'
o

% echo 'one two three' | awk '{FS="n" ; OFS=":" ; $1 = $1 ; print}'
one:two:three
```

Note that I'm not using GNU awk:

```
% awk --version
awk version 20200816
```

But I'd expect the same of GNU awk.